# array_push в json_массив PHP

Tags: php

Как в массив такого вида

```
$json = json_decode('
        [{
            "eventId": "1",
            "quantity": "2"
        }, {
            "eventId": "2",
            "quantity": "4"
        }]
        ');
```

Занести еще одну запись?

Comment: Сперва перевести JSON в массив (json_decode), и array_push сделать не подходит?

Comment: Обновил суть вопроса

Comment: Не надо менять суть вопроса, особенно после того как появился хотя бы один ответ. Если есть другой вопрос - задавай новый

Comment: @ГромСупиев, прочитайте про второй аргумент функции [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode.php). Для поиска по массиву - можете попробовать посмотреть все функции php для [работы с массивами](http://php.net/manual/ru/ref.array.php), там есть краткие описания к ним. В крайнем случае, если ничего не подходит - всегда можно foreach.

Comment: @Александр Белинский теперь вам стало понятно _при чем здесь json_ ? Это и надо было в ответе упомянуть.

Answer (score 0):

Берешь и заносишь:

```
$json[] = [
    'eventId' => '3',
    'quantity' => '4'
];
```

Не понял только, при чем здесь json.

[array_push](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-push.php), [array_unshift](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-unshift.php)

Comment: если не поняли, то сперва разберитесь в сути проблемы, а потом давайте ответы.

Comment: @Эдуард, читаю вопрос: "как в массив такого вида ... занести еще одну запись" - обращаю внимание, что в переменной 'json' хранится массив, просто обычный массив, никакого "духа json-а" там нет. Далее вопрос "как занести еще одну запись" - взял и занёс, написал ответ. Параллельно решил уточнить - всё же, при чем здесь был json? Непонятно Ваше замечание. Разбираться здесь мне ни с чем не нужно.